# Formik & react-bootstrap: refresh feedback after form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

I use Formik and react-bootstrap.
When the form is submitted, validation errors from the backend can occur.
I want to update the form feedback fields accordingly. I use the setErrors Method,
but the feedback element is not updated and the input element doesn't get red.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Field, ErrorMessage, useFormik } from 'formik';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const LoginForm = () => {

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues = {{ userid: '', password: ''}}
      onSubmit = {(values, { setSubmitting, setErrors }) => {
        console.log("Formsub: " + JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        setErrors({userid: 'invalid login.'});
        setSubmitting(false);
      }}
    >
      {({
        handleSubmit,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        isSubmitting,
        values,
        touched,
        isValid,
        errors,
      }) => (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        Errors: {errors.userid}
        <Row className="mb-3">
          <Form.Group md="4" controlId="validationUserid">
            <Form.Label>Userid:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" name="userid" 
              onChange={handleChange} value={values.userid} 
              isValid={touched.userid && !errors.userid}
            />
            <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">{errors.userid}</Form.Control.Feedback>
          </Form.Group>
        </Row>
        <Button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Submit form</Button>
      </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Do I have to trigger the refresh of the form elements with the error marking manually?
If so, how?
Or is there a problem in my code that prevents the form from updating?